# The speed of learning and prior

Tags: algebra-precalculus, bayesian

If I know 
    $$\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta}<\frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\gamma}$$
can I know the sign of 
$$\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha+1+\beta}<\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda+1+\gamma} $$
And the sign of 
$$(\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha+1+\beta}-\frac{\alpha}{\alpha+\beta})-(\frac{\lambda+1}{\lambda+1+\gamma}- \frac{\lambda}{\lambda+\gamma})$$

The background of this question is that I want to know if the speed of learning for beta distribution is affected by the prior. If I have a smaller prior, do I learn faster ?

Comment: Just to make the language more poeticly euphonious, I might have written this as $\dfrac\alpha{\alpha+\beta}<\dfrac\kappa{\kappa+\lambda}$.  That way each fraction involves two adjacent letters of the alphabet, with the first letter in one role and the second in the other. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming everything is positive, the first inequality is equivalent to $\alpha\gamma<\lambda\beta$ and the second to $(\alpha+1)\gamma<(\lambda+1)\beta$, or to $\alpha\gamma+\gamma<\lambda\beta+\beta$.

So the question is: If

$$\alpha\gamma<\lambda\beta,\tag 1$$

then does it follow that $\alpha\gamma+\gamma<\lambda\beta+\beta$, or

$$(\alpha+1)\beta<(\lambda+1)\gamma\text{ ?}\tag 2$$

So I would try to figure out what the spaces of solutions of $(1)$ and $(2)$ within the space $\alpha,\beta,\gamma,\lambda>0$ look like.